# ROC curve from the linear regression model made of continuous values

Tags: python, linear-regression, roc, auc

I want make a model with continuous values. So, before I split a data.

[image]

```
X = data[col_list]
y = data['death rate']
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=0)
```

First, I made the model with 'sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression'.

```
#instantiate the model
lin_regression = LinearRegression()

#fit the model using the training data
lin_regression.fit(X_train,y_train)

#define metrics
y_predicted = lin_regression.predict(X_test)
fpr, tpr, _ = metrics.roc_curve(y_test,  y_predicted)
```

But the code didn't work. It said 'ValueError: continuous format is not supported'.

After then I used 'from sklearn import svm' to handle it.

```
random_state = np.random.RandomState(0)

#instantiate the model
classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(
    svm.SVC(kernel="linear", probability=True, random_state=random_state)
)

#fit the model using the training data
y_score = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).decision_function(X_test)
```

But it still didn't work with 'ValueError:Unknown label type'.
I found that original y data format, whichis is from the site I referenced, is (n x 3)array and it's binary values.
for example, y_train=[[0,1,1],[0,1,0],...].

My question is

1. Can Linear regression model has ROC curve?
2. If it can, how to make it in python?

Comment: No, ROC is meant for classification problems. It takes into consideration the values true positive, true negative, false positive and false negative where every input can be put only in one category.

Comment: Nope, you have a classification problem and ROC is meant for classification problems or problems where you can say that is either right or wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compute a ROC curve from a regression model since you can't define true positives, true negatives, false positives and false negatives. The only solution could be to define a threshold and to binarize the y variable as:

```
y_bin = np.zeros_like(y_test)
y_bin[y_test>=threshold] = 1

fpr, tpr, _ = metrics.roc_curve(y_bin,  y_predicted)
```

Otherwise you can apply others metrics as made in:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031320313002665